# Does one get two reputation points for replying to a comment on a closed question?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Under [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/165687/what-part-of-mathematics-deals-with-what-makes-a-valid-idea-mathematical-an?noredirect=1#comment445019_165687) I posted a comment, to which someone replied, and then I replied to that. I was surprised to see that at that moment I got two reputation points because of something about that question. How does that work?

Comment: [You had an accepted edit to an answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/165698/2)

Comment: [You can also check your reputation page](https://i.imgur.com/Cr8O0n3.png)

Answer (score 13):

Nope. Comments, and upvotes on comments, do not result in any reputation changes.

After looking at your [reputation history](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/7229/michael-hardy?tab=reputation), it looks like you currently sit at a positive 2 to your reputation today, with the only reputation change being that you [submitted a suggested edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/98995) that was approved. This occurred at 17:25:46 UTC, and [this comment of yours](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/165687/what-part-of-mathematics-deals-with-what-makes-a-valid-idea-mathematical-an?noredirect=1#comment445030_165687) was posted at 17:55. With about a half hour in between, it's possible that you just didn't notice the reputation change until later, or [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) is messing with you.

Answer (score 2):

You get +2 rep for an approved edit.

You [got one approved](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/98995) at the time of your comment which explains your confusion.

This is visible on your [activity page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/7229/michael-hardy?tab=reputation).